# Preventing Firefox to add xmlns="" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I don't know why, Firefox adds xmlns="" to my xml elements
Here's my base xml document. I would like, in javascript, to add a **Relationship**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId8" Target="endnotes.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/endnotes"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId13" Target="footer1.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footer"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId3" Target="styles.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId7" Target="footnotes.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footnotes"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId12" Target="header1.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId2" Target="numbering.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/numbering"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Target="../customXml/item1.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/customXml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId6" Target="webSettings.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/webSettings"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId11" Target="media/image3.png" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId5" Target="settings.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/settings"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId15" Target="theme/theme1.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/theme"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId10" Target="media/image2.png" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId4" Target="stylesWithEffects.xml" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/stylesWithEffects"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId9" Target="media/image1.png" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId14" Target="fontTable.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/fontTable"/>
</Relationships>
```

The code works fine in Chrome, but adds xmlns="" as an attribute of Relationship in Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/USLFs/2/

I have found here [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295523/xelement-add-function-adds-xmlns-to-the-xelement) that it is probably linked to the fact that I should set the same Namespace for the child element as for the root element.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't there's a way to remove this behaviour out of Firefox, except for using a regex or string replace.