# Getting "<kml:..." everywhere, updating a Kml file

Tags: c#, namespaces, linq-to-xml, kml, google-earth

I'm reading in a Kml file, changing the placemarks' names, and saving it again.

```
var KmlFile = XDocument.Load("C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\GeotagService\\Kml\\Photographs.kml");

XNamespace KmlNamespace = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

// find the Placemarks in the Photos folder
IEnumerable<XElement> Placemarks = KmlFile.Element(KmlNamespace + "kml").Element(KmlNamespace + "Document").Element(KmlNamespace + "Folder").Elements(KmlNamespace + "Placemark");

foreach (XElement p in Placemarks){
    p.Element(KmlNamespace + "name").Value = "testing";
}

KmlFile.Save("C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\GeotagService\\Kml\\Photographs.kml");
```

When I save it however, **every** element is prefixed with `<kml:`, like this:

```
<kml:Folder>
  <kml:name>Photos</kml:name>
  <kml:open>1</kml:open>
  <kml:Placemark>
    <kml:name>testing</kml:name>
    <kml:LookAt>
      <kml:longitude>-10.02717694938161</kml:longitude>
      <kml:latitude>53.48672543547379</kml:latitude>
      <kml:altitude>0</kml:altitude>
    </kml:LookAt>
    <kml:styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin1</kml:styleUrl>
    <kml:Point>
       <kml:coordinates>-10.02867619360582,53.48651240326751,0</kml:coordinates>
    </kml:Point>
 </kml:Placemark>...
```

Tomalak's comment on [this question about blank xmlns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803636/linq-to-xml-get-rid-of-blank-xmlns) gives me a clue that it might be inconsistencies between the namespaces of the document and the elements, but I can't see how I'm doing that. Anyone know?

**EDIT**: Original document (in part):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <Document>
        <name>Connemara.net Photographs</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Style id="sh_ylw-pushpin0">
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>1.3</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
        <Folder>
            <name>Photos</name>
            <open>1</open>
            <Placemark>
                <name>Id:579</name>
                <LookAt>
                    <longitude>-10.02717694938161</longitude>
                    <latitude>53.48672543547379</latitude>
                    <altitude>0</altitude>
                    <range>213.2931913230747</range>
                    <tilt>75.17546328115256</tilt>
                    <heading>69.89736514305363</heading>
                    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                    <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
                </LookAt>
                <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin1</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-10.02867619360582,53.48651240326751,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
...
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: What does the original document look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it - the problem is that the original document starts like this:

```
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
      xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" 
      xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
      xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

LINQ to XML sees that there's a specific alias for the KML namespace, so uses that. If you remove that attribute, it works fine:

```
var explicitNs = KmlFile.Root.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "kml");
if (explicitNs != null)
{
    explicitNs.Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [namespace manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspxx). Here's an example using XPath to select the necessary tags and then update their value:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kml = XDocument.Load("test.kml");
        var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        ns.AddNamespace("kml", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
        var names = kml.XPathSelectElements("//kml:Placemark/kml:name", ns);
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            name.Value = "testing";
        }
        kml.Save("test.kml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. The fact that you are naming your local variables start with an uppercase letter made me think that you are using some special library to parse kml, especially this statement was quite ambiguous for me: `KmlFile.Element` :-)