# Not able to output an xml document without a prefix in the namespace

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I am creating an xml document from Sql Server data using C# and XElement and the client spec requires an attribute namespace xmlns in the main tag (case is the main tag).
Here is the example from their spec:

```
<case techname="Client" count="4" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/NBAppSchema.xsd">
```

My problem is that I am getting an error in C# trying to output this 'case' tag's xmlns attribute with using a prefix.
(error: The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://example.com/xmlns1' within the same start element tag.)

When I include a prefix, it generates the xml fine only the client tells me that when they try to load it, it errors out.
Example with prefix:

```
<case techname="Client" count="4" xmlns:prfx="http://tempuri.org/NBAppSchema.xsd">
```

Code:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/NBAppSchema.xsd";
XElement mainCaseTag = new XElement("case", new XAttribute("techname", "Univers"), new XAttribute("count", totalApplicationCount), new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "prfx", ns));
```

I would like to output this attribute as the first example without the prefix.
I have tried to research, but cannot find or understand how to output this xml file with a namespace without the prefix.

Comment: Why use `XNamespace.Xmlns + "prfx"`?

Comment: I need to include a namespace as shown without the prefix but when I remove it, C# is giving me compile error as shown.

Comment: I've tried to just add an attribute ("xmlns", "http://tempuri.org/NBAppSchema.xsd") and I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/NBAppSchema.xsd";      
var doc2 = new XDocument(
    new XElement(ns + "root",
        new XAttribute("attr1", "val1"), 
        new XElement(ns + "SubNode")));
Console.WriteLine(doc2.ToString());
```

And the [demo](http://dotnetfiddle.net/4pHgd0) with 2 options.

Comment: Hi Tony/John, great thank you. I think that option #2 is what I'm looking for only how do I add all my nodes and subnodes in this format. My setup is a little different in that I create a main element (case) adding subnodes to nodes and adding nodes to the main element case. At the end I XDocument xmlFile = new XDocument(caseTag) and then xmlFile.Save(fileName);....how can I accomplish this with the way you structured your option#2. Sorry I am new to XML and there are so many ways!!

Comment: Ok so I'm restructuring the way I build the xml by creating the XDocument doc = (new XDocument(new XElement(ns + "case", new XAttribute("techname", "Client"),
new XElement("casename", caseName) etc....

Only now it is putting xmlns="" in each node...is there a way to not have this in each node?
Thanks again!

Comment: ah...this helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084/empty-namespace-using-linq-xml.
put ns + before each node and then it does not include the blank ns = ""

Comment: ah ha, finally, all I had to do was put ns + in front of all nodes and it than will output the xmlns="http://tempuri.org/NBAppSchema.xsd" in the main node and it will ignore the empty xmlns="" in each node and subnode!! Nice...